# Passing extra parameter through GetAll method of webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How to pass an extra parameter through a Get method of **webapi** because when i pass 
 `GetALL(int page,int limit,int start)` it works fine but when in passed one more parameters that is optional and may be null it throws error.

```
GetAll(int page,int limit,int start,string ? search)
```

What is the best way to make it working

Answer (score 0):

In Web API optional parameters are those which can be nulled.

If you have type values like int or DateTime, you need to make them nullableby using the `?` syntax.

But when they're classes instead of value type, they are directly convertible to null, so you don't need to, and can not, mark them as nullable. SO, your method signature must be simply this:

```
 GetAll(int page,int limit,int start,string search)
```

If you wanted `page`, `limit` or `start` to be nullable, you should declare them as `int?`. So, int he signature above this 3 parameters are compulsory, and the last one optional.

**EDIT, for OP comment**

When you use the default routing for Web API the only way to choose the right method is by parameter matching, i.e. the parameters in the request must match the parameters in the action **including the optional parameters**. So, there are two ways to make it work:

- post the optional parameters as empty parameters. For your case, provided you're using the query string, include a `&search=` in the URL
- modify the routes, so that the parameters are provided as route parameters, and define the search parameter as optional

You can also completely modify the web API routing by including the action in the route. In that case, you have to specify the action in the URLs to invoke the action, but the method can be chosen by action name (given by method name or `Action` attribute), and not by parameter matching. In that case you don't need to provide the optional parameters. It will work like MVC routing.

Comment: When i do this add the last parameter i loose the restful services i received an error that no such method available matching.........with three int parameters it works fine